# Making enum to combo box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

I'd like my *enum*'s to generate combo boxes, instead of plain input fields. Just like when we include related classes from other - those are pickable from a list.

How can I do that automatically? I know how to do that from the code but I'd like the automatic code generator for a view to do that for me.

Is it at all possible?!

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9166665. Then you just need to create an editor template called `Enum.cshtml` that builds your combo box from the enum members.

Comment: There are several same questions: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656758/mvc3-razor-dropdownlistfor-enums